# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to open a JSP, but I'm getting below error.

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile
>   class for JSP

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.validateImport(Node.java:610)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.addImport(Node.java:591)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parsePageDirective(Parser.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1787)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:136)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

It's referring to this line in my JSP

```
<%@page import="Basiccalculator.*;" %>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try removing the ';' from your import. I am not sure what server you are using but I found this for tomcat versions 7.057 and later. Take a look at [this](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/206211847-Upgrade-to-Tomcat-7-0-57-and-8-0-15-or-Later-may-Cause-JSP-Compilation-Error-HTTP-Status-500-Unable-to-compile-class-for-JSP-on-JSP-Page)

Comment: I'm using tomcat 8.0 sir

Comment: did you try to remove the ';' just to see if that fixed it?

Comment: Works for me. I am using `apache-tomcat-7.0.73`.thanks,

Comment: Is there any way we can get around that ? I mean we have so many JSP pages which they have used semicolon during the update its hectic to change each and every jsp,do we have other way ??