# How to solve this - HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: java, tomcat

Jsp Program

- I am using jdk 1.7.0_76
- tomcat 7 version
- List item
- I'm getting error like this Unable to compile class for JSP, please send me the solution

### java jsp program

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*;" %>
<%! int hno;
String hname,address;  %>
<%

try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Nipul1DSN","","");

    Statement st=cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Hospital");
%>
    <table border="1" width="40%">
        <tr>
            <td>Hospital No</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
        <%  while(rs.next()) {
            %>
            <tr> <td><%= rs.getInt("hno") %></td>
            <td><%= rs.getString("hname") %></td>
            <td><%= rs.getString("address") %></td>
            </tr>
        <%
        }
    cn.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{      
    out.println(e);      
}
%>
</body></html>
```

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Unable to compile class for JSP
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
> > org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:675)
> > org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
> > org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.validateImport(Node.java:628)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.addImport(Node.java:609)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parsePageDirective(Parser.java:352)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:473)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1773)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:135)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:237)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:394)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:370)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
> org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.109**

Please solve this error, I have also tried with java jdk 6 version but it didn't work

Comment: Give it a try first and come back with code you have tried and explain where you're stuck at.

Comment: I am getting error , mentioned in the 2nd block , at first try

Comment: atleast format your code. And then search:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292298/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-page-directive-invalid-value-for-import/36292471

Answer (score 1):

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292298/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-page-directive-invalid-value-for-import/36292471)

Better if you:

- Search first
- Format code
- Give your code try-catch

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ';' from your import. I am not sure what server you are using but I found this for tomcat versions 7.057 and later.